# Completion of product of complete sigma algebras

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Is it true that if $(X_1,\Sigma_1, \mu_1)$ and $(X_2,\Sigma_2,\mu_2)$ and $(X_3,\Sigma_3,\mu_3)$ are all $\sigma$-finite, complete measure spaces, that $((\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2)^{\ast} \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast} = (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast}$, where $^{\ast}$ is completion and both the LHS and RHS $\sigma$-algebras are interpreted as being on $X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3$ (i.e. taking $((a,b),c) = (a,b,c)$ in this context).

This happens to be true if each of the measurable spaces above are $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) ^{\ast}, \lambda)$ and so I suspect via a similar proof as in this case, it should be true for the completions of borel sigma-algebras of separable metric spaces, perhaps topological spaces. Is it true in the general case?

Edit: It is true in the general case, and only $\sigma$-finiteness is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think so, although I might be wrong. Here is my idea (written not too formally), feel free to say if you agree or disagree:

Recall that the product $\sigma$-algebra is generated by the semi-algebra of product sets. Moreover, we know that the completion is unique. So by Caratheodory, it's enough to check your questions on the corresponding semi-algebras - even before taking the completion.
So esentially it boils down to asking if the semi-algebras of both $((\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2) \otimes \Sigma_3)$ and $(\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3)$ are identical as families of product sets - and they are. And since a measure $0$ set in the semi-algebra must be measure $0$ in one or more of its components, you can take the completion "associatively".

Comment: I agree with you, your reply gave me the confidence to try and prove it formally, I will post my solution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

We use the following lemmas:

Lemma 1:

Given $(X_i,\Sigma_i,\mu_i)$ are $\sigma$-finite measure spaces for $i=1,2,3$:

$(X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3, (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2) \otimes \Sigma_3 , (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2) \otimes \mu_3)) = (X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 , \Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3, \mu_1 \otimes \mu_2 \otimes \mu_3)$

Lemma 2:

$(X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3, (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2) \otimes \Sigma_3 , (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2) \otimes \mu_3) \leq (X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3, (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2)^{\ast} \otimes \Sigma_3 , (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)^{\ast} \otimes \mu_3 )$

Proof:

We show that

$$(X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 , (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2)^{\ast} \otimes \Sigma_3 , (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)^{\ast} \otimes \mu_3 )  \leq           
      (X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 , (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast}, (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2 \otimes \mu_3)^{\ast})$$

Note $\{E \times F : E \in (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2)^{\ast}, F \in \Sigma_3 \}$ generates $(\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2)^{\ast} \otimes \Sigma_3$. It also contains an exhausting sequence (with respect to $(\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)^{\ast} \otimes \mu_3$) for $X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3$. If we show that $(\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2) \otimes \mu_3$ and $(\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2 \otimes \mu_3)^{\ast}$ agree on this generating set, then by a corollary of the $\pi - \lambda$ theorem we will show the desired above inequality. If $E \times F$ is a member of the generating set, then $E = E' \cup H$, where $E' \in \Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2$ and $H \subset N \in \Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2$ such that $(\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)(N) = 0$.

Then we have that $E \times F = E'\times F \cup H \times F \subset E' \times F \cup N \times F$, and by Lemma 1 $(\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2 \otimes \mu_3)^{\ast}(N \times F) = (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2 \otimes \mu_3)(N \times F) = (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)(N) * (\mu_3)(F) = 0$. This shows that $E \times F \in (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast}$, and finally we have that $(\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2 \otimes \mu_3)^{\ast}(E \times F) =  (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2 \otimes \mu_3)(E' \times F) = (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)^{\ast}(E')*\mu_3(F)$ which gives the desired result.

It follows that $$(X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 , ((\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2)^{\ast} \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast} , ((\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)^{\ast} \otimes \mu_3 )^{\ast})  \leq           
      (X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 , (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast}, (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2 \otimes \mu_3)^{\ast})$$

Lemma 2 then gives that :

$(X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3, ((\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2) \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast} , ((\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2) \otimes \mu_3)^{\ast}) \leq (X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3, ((\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2)^{\ast} \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast} , ((\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)^{\ast} \otimes \mu_3)^{\ast} ) $

by taking the completions of both measure spaces on either side of the inequality.

Which finally, gives:

$$(X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 , ((\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2)^{\ast} \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast} , ((\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2)^{\ast} \otimes \mu_3 )^{\ast})  =            
      (X_1 \times X_2 \times X_3 , (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast}, (\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2 \otimes \mu_3)^{\ast})$$

In particular, $((\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2)^{\ast} \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast} =  (\Sigma_1 \otimes \Sigma_2 \otimes \Sigma_3)^{\ast}$